# How to calculate the Short Circuit current of a small DC circuit?

Tags: short-circuit, lighting, dali

I need to do a short circuit test for my DALI slave device. I have observed a maximum load of 140W at 210V-rms (Load current = 650 mA , PF = 0.975). I have to do a short circuit at the load side and I have no idea how much current will be in an SC.

How can I calculate the short circuit current at this point? What kind of switch I have to use for this test for a period ranging from 1 sec to 5 mins.

Thank you.

Comment: Add a schematic of your test setup. Add information about this "DALI" device. As it is now, unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to calculate the prospective short-circuit current based on the power source impedance and the internal components. You will need to make some assumptions about the status of any internal current limiting circuitry. There may be information in the DALI standards that needs to be considered. There may be additional standards that would be applicable according to the regional safety certification that you intend to obtain.